# struggling with understanding this basic linked list function

Tags: python

the following node class is given:

```
class Node:  
  def __init__(self, value):  
    self.value = value   
    self.next = None
```

below is the function i'm having trouble understanding: on the answer key, it says that the purpose of the function is to remove every other element starting from the second element in linked list lnk. however, from what i can see, it just deletes removes every element until the final one is remaining. how am i not correct?

```
def mystery1(lnk: Node):   
  while lnk and lnk.next:   
    lnk.next = lnk.next.next   
    lnk = lnk.next
```

Comment: Play computer and see what is actually happening.

Comment: testing it in python does not help me understand it. the answer key says that the function removes every other element of lst starting from the second element. but i don't understand why

Comment: Don't run the code, *play computer.* You are the computer. Execute it step by step yourself.

Comment: i figured it out, the variable lnk created within the function is treated as a local variable